# мне нужно понять откуда берется вторая ссылка. сайт sofascore.com

Tags: python, json, парсер

Веб-сайт https://www.sofascore.com/ru/tennis

Бот парсил очки в гейме(первой ссылки)
я отправлял ссылки на матч телеграмм бота, а мне приходил парсинг этого матча

Был работающий телеграмм бот. изменился макет сайта, и бот встал. Подскажите откуда берутся выбранные значения. Первая ссылка указывает на сам матч, а следующая ссылка на игрока и элемент его имени. Я не понимаю, откуда взялась вторая выделенная ссылка. Потому что она не существует ни на странице матча, ни на личной странице игрока, если вы открываете панель разработчика.

```
import requests
import lxml.etree
import time
import json
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler

parser = lxml.etree.HTMLParser(encoding = 'utf-8')

class Event:
    def __getEvent(self):
        r = requests.get(url='https://www.sofascore.com/event/{}/general/json?_={}'.format(self.id, int(time.time())))
        return r.json()

    def __getPlayer(self, id):
        r = requests.get(url='https://www.sofascore.com/team/tennis/a/{}'.format(id))
        r.encoding = 'utf-8'
        tree = lxml.etree.fromstring(r.text, parser = parser)
        name = tree.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/main/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/h3")[0].text
        return {
            'id': id,
            'name': name.strip()
        }
```